# Spring Boot MongoDB shallow loading DocumentReferences

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I'm using Sping-Boot and MongoDB to build an application. I have different entities/documents liked via the `@DocumentReference` annotation which works great so far. I checked the database and Spring converts the document reference to an ObjectId as intended.

When loading the data from the database however using either mongoTemplate or the MongoRepository all referenced documents are loaded too. With growing data I'm concerned that this will put an extensive load on my system. Is there a way to write the query in such a way that only certain document references are loaded? Is there a way to create a 'shallow' query or would I have to create a separate entity?